# Why won't if clause return nationality

Tags: mysql, if-statement

In the following SQL select statement, I want nationality to print if name is null, and I have a SQL clause's if syntax working, but am not seeing nationality print out in the following:

```
table test2

id           integer
case         integer
nationality  char(10)
name         char(24)

1 1 france  ""
2 2 england john

select t.id, 
       if(t.name is null, t.nationality, t.name) 
       as name_equivalent 
from   test2 t;
```

produces 
   id name_equivalent

---

```
1 ""
2 john
```

Why is that?
Thank You.

Comment: Some databases consider empty string and null equivalent (Oracle for example) whilst others treat them as different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` is not equivalent to the empty string. The empty string `''` is a valid form of data, `null` indicates there is no data present.

Try either

```
if (t.name is null or t.name='', t.nationality, t.name)
```

Or set the name in the first column to null

```
1 1 france null
```

Answer (score 2):

You're checking if the name is null, but it was set to an empty string. To check for both, you need:

```
if(t.name is null or t.name='', t.nationality, t.name)
```

Comment: Although its clear from your code, you could improve your answer tp explain why this works. e.g. Zero Length string isn't the same as null. Also `TRIM(t.name) = ''` wouldn't hurt

Comment: @ConradFrix I elaborated on the answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like France's name field is actually an empty string, and not null. You need to also account for it being empty in your select statement. Such as `t.name = ''`